# How to use for in loop decrement condition in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, for-in-loop, xcode7.3

I can use the for in loop in Swift through this code

```
   for i in 0..<5
{
    print ("Four multiplied by \(i) results in \(i*4)" )
}
```

But how do i use the for with less than ">" condition.

```
  for i in 10>..5
{
    print ("Four multiplied by \(i) results in \(i*4)" )
}
```

It shows  **error: '>' is not a postfix unary operator
for i in 10>..5**

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 this is not the c-style statement. Please understand the question and post comments

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Hey Hey .... Nice attitude man... Posting meaningless comments and deleting afterwards. What man... ??? Its not right

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Have a nice day man...

Comment: @AshleyRodrigues and I am just trying to help you .. but you think if its meaningless than its ok ...

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I appreciate your help. But i couldn't help myself when you posted my question as a duplicate of c-style syntax... Anyways glad to meet you..

Comment: @AshleyRodrigues may be its not duplicate ... but atleast you need to check ... if its wrong than no one gonna close your question .. thats it .. dont be so rude on such incident .. it happens in SO

Comment: @AshleyRodrigues you don't have right to do rudely behave like this any people on SO. If it's not duplicate then you can simply tell the person like this is not duplicate. what is the meaning of "Please learn to comment wisely", "update yourself". please give respect to all the people. All people are trying to help each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the stride() method:

```
for i in 10.stride(to: 5, by: -1) {
     print ("Four multiplied by \(i) results in \(i*4)" )
}
```

This will increment through 10, 9, 8, 7, and 6.  If you want 5 to be included, use `through:` instead:

```
for i in 10.stride(through: 5, by: -1) {
     print ("Four multiplied by \(i) results in \(i*4)" )
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Bro. It helped.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!